# php codeigniter why should we use models when there is very little business login in a controller

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter framework. Most of the modules are very simple and they just have `SELECT * FROM TABLE` and a pagination. So the `index()` function would have just three lines of code. In this case, what is the purpose of including model in the structure. Do we use models compulsory to maintain standard or can we exclude according to the simplicity of the total business logic in that module?

Some times I need to fetch data from three tables other than the main iteration. and I am replicating this in three function in one controller. Hope for this I can use models.

I would appreciate your suggestions and comments on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nobody is forcing you to implement in this way. The MVC is just a best practice. You can use a fat controller, a fat model or no model at all. After a while you will realize the need for the model/controller separation and you can implement that when time comes.

As a side note I see you are using old fashion queries like Select *. Did you try the active record provided by CI ?

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: *(sidenote)* CI's ActiveRecord is not an ActiveRecord. It's not even "a modified version of the Active Record Database Pattern" as they claim. It's a very simple Query Builder pattern.

Answer (score 2):

The main idea of MVC design pattern is to separate the presentation layer, controller (glue layer) and data layer (model).

So it doesn't matter whether it is 3 or 100 lines - if you follow mvc-idea, then you put all the stuff that is related to data to the model.

Further reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93View%E2%80%93Controller#Concepts